# How to get error icon below edit text in android?

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

I don't know a lot about the designs in Android. I have tried to use an error message in the edit text but they don't work well for me. They don't look good.

I have implemented Material.io in my application but the error looks something like this:

[image: Default image of error in edit text]

I want to get the error icon below the edit text like this:

[image: Image of edit text with error!]

What should I do to get this?

Thanks for having a look at this question!

Comment: use material components

Comment: @Rashiq Thanks for your answer but Can you please elaborate?

I use com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout in XML and TextInputLayout . setError to set error and it provides the error icon inside the edit text? Can you explain me plesae?

Comment: @KishorKumarNeupane, may i know the progress? did you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Found solution!
You can find this "ErrorView" and set to it your own paddings like that:

```
(yourTextInputLayout.getAllChildren().last().parent?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.let {
    it.setPadding(0, it.paddingTop, it.paddingRight, it.paddingBottom)
}
```

Where getAllChildren() is:

```
fun View.getAllChildren(): List<View> {
val result = ArrayList<View>()
if (this !is ViewGroup) {
    result.add(this)
} else {
    for (index in 0 until this.childCount) {
        val child = this.getChildAt(index)
        result.addAll(child.getAllChildren())
    }
}
return result
```

}

You can also add drawableStart to it like this:

```
yourTextInputLayout.getAllChildren().last().let {
            if (it is AppCompatTextView) {
                it.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.yourDrawable, 0, 0, 0)
            }
        }
```

IMPORTANT! You must do it after u did this:

```
yourInputLayout.isErrorEnabled = true
yourInputLayout.error = "some error message here"
```

final result:

```
yourInputLayout.isErrorEnabled = true
yourInputLayout.error = "some error message here"

(yourTextInputLayout.getAllChildren().last().parent?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.let {
it.setPadding(0, it.paddingTop, it.paddingRight, it.paddingBottom)
}

yourTextInputLayout.getAllChildren().last().let {
            if (it is AppCompatTextView) {
                it.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.yourDrawable, 0, 0, 0)
            }
        }

fun View.getAllChildren(): List<View> {
val result = ArrayList<View>()
if (this !is ViewGroup) {
    result.add(this)
} else {
    for (index in 0 until this.childCount) {
        val child = this.getChildAt(index)
        result.addAll(child.getAllChildren())
    }
}
return result
```

}

Comment: Worked for me, After looking into many solutions and documentation. This one finally worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this code

```
TextInputLayout passwordInputLayout = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.textField_p);
 
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
passwordInputLayout.setError(null)
          yourMethod();

            }

            }
        });
public void yourMethod (){
             
passwordInputLayout.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.your_message));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your view on how to solve the problem, but I think the method does is just creates a error message of the material UI with a error sign inside the edit text box. I want the error sign before the error message! Hope you understood my problem!